# IndexError: string index out of range/ problem in tuples

Tags: python, list

I'm having difficulty creating tuples to make it easier to store information in the list due to the error mentioned in the title.

This is the code:

```
qntd_alunos = int(input('Número de alunos:'))

for aluno in range(qntd_alunos+1):
    print(f'Digite as respotas do aluno {aluno+1}')
    for prova in range(qntd_questoes):    
        resp_alunos = str(input(f'Digite a resposta da {prova+1} questão:'))
        for num in range(qntd_questoes):
            correcao = (resp_alunos[aluno])
            respostas_alunos.append(correcao)
```

Comment: qntd_questoes  & respostas_alunos are not defined

Comment: resp_alunos is reset for each aluno, so the line `correcao = (resp_alunos[aluno])` will throw IndexError when `len(resp_alunos) < (aluno+1)`. you should append the result of your input to resp_alunos instead of assigning it